# Crash due to FragmentTransaction animation on Samsung S3

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm facing a crash, `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 21307` on **Samsung S3** device when using animations for `FragmentTransaction`.

Code:

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_right, R.anim.slide_out_to_left, R.anim.slide_in_from_left, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);
```

Animation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
     android:shareInterpolator="true">
  <translate
      android:duration="@integer/animation_duration"
      android:fromXDelta="100%"
      android:toXDelta="0%"/>
  <alpha
      android:duration="@integer/animation_duration"
      android:fromAlpha="0"
      android:toAlpha="1"/>
</set>
```

Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185457) in Android's Support Lib and resolved in versions 23.0.1 and above.